# Batch update fails when connecting to an "old" column family with DataStax driver

Tags: java, python, cassandra, cql, datastax

I have a Cassandra process that was created and defined in early Cassandra versions. So far, we used an hector driver to connect to it. Im in a process of changing the driver to DataStax to enjoy the CQL new features and to allow asynchronous access.

I encounter some problems in the process of doing that transition. I've read [this upgrade guide](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3) which shed some light though I still encounter some problems.

The biggest one is that I cant access the keyspace with a protocol version bigger than one. When I try the following python code:

```
cass4 = Cluster(['MyIp'])
cass4.protocol_version = 2
session = cass4.connect('myKeySpace')
```

This code yields the following errors and warnings:

```
ERROR:cassandra.connection:Closing connection <AsyncoreConnection(4849045328) IP:9042> due to protocol error: code=000a [Protocol error] message="Invalid or unsupported protocol version: 2"
WARNING:cassandra.cluster:Downgrading core protocol version from 2 to 1 for IP
WARNING:cassandra.metadata:Building table metadata with no column meta for keyspace
```

With the Java driver, I simply get a `NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed` connection error if im trying to connect with a protocol version bigger than 1.

This connection problem is causing me a lot of trouble building an appropriate Java DAO. for example, if Im trying to do batch update, e.g.:

```
BatchStatment batch = new BatchStatement()
batch.add(somePreparedStatement)
cqlSession.executeAsync(batch)
```

I get the following error:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnsupportedFeatureException: Unsupported feature with the native protocol version 1 (which is currently in use): Protocol level batching is not supported
```

Running a "BEGIN BATCH.." operation directly on a cluster node using cqlsh works, So I know this CQL command can be executed, but I dont know how to prepare it in Java and execute it with protocol version 1. Also, the cassandra and CQL version an the cluster seems appropriate:

```
[cqlsh 3.1.7 | Cassandra 1.2.13.2 | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.36.2]
```

So, questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Can I connect to that keyspace with a protocol version greater than 1?
3. If not, Can I somehow bypass this batch update problem?

Comment: Does this work on a brand new keyspace? What Cassandra version are you using?

Comment: Im using Cassandra 1.2.13.2. Ill try the code on a brad new keyspace and let you know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this issue was eventually found [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra):

> Can I combine Batches and PreparedStatements?
>
> Starting with Cassandra 2.0 and the corresponding versions of the C#,
>   Java, and Python drivers, PreparedStatements can be used in batch
>   operations (nb before that you could still prepare a complete batch
>   operation, but you’d need to know apriori the number of statements
>   that will be included).

Since my Cassandra version is 1.2xx, I cant use batch updates and prepared statements.

A work around is to create the query as a string (Ya, that's dirty) and than execute the string query.